# SSHLibrary in Robot Framework failed on timeout argument on Mac

Tags: python, macos, testing, ssh, robotframework

I used fresh installation of Robot Framework on my Mac (i repeated this on Mac Air and Mac Pro with the same result) and when I want use example from the [official SSHLibrary site](http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/latest/SSHLibrary.html#Example)
with this command which I believe is correct:

```
robot --loglevel TRACE:TRACE login_tests/ssh.robot
```

it returns in terminal:

```
Suite setup failed: 
TypeError: _custom_start_client() got an unexpected keyword argument 'timeout'
```

I can find this in log file:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/SSHLibrary/library.py", line 792, in login
    return self._login(self.current.login, username, password, delay)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/SSHLibrary/library.py", line 832, in _login
    login_output = login_method(username, *args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/SSHLibrary/abstractclient.py", line 146, in login
    self._login(username, password, look_for_keys=look_for_keys)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/SSHLibrary/pythonclient.py", line 69, in _login
    timeout=float(self.config.timeout))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 338, in connect
    t.start_client(timeout=timeout)
```

Python 2.7.10
Robot Framework 3.0 (Python 2.7.10 on darwin)

[Image of the screenshot of the log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USRfu.png)

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I also used in Settings `Library    SSHLibrary   5 minutes` with no results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably encountered the issue mentioned on [#157 on SSHLibrary](https://github.com/robotframework/SSHLibrary/issues/157), caused by the new version of Paramiko. Try to downgrade Paramiko with:`pip install -U paramiko==2.0.2` and retest again.

(If it works, you should then keep an eye on new fixes releases for this issue, either on Paramiko or SSHLibrary)

Comment: Bug should be fixed already. [SSHLibrary 2.1.3](https://github.com/robotframework/SSHLibrary/releases/tag/2.1.3)